# What can be the source of this docker-compose error message: ... Cannot set property TasksAccounting, or unknown property

Tags: rhel, docker

Im running a RHEL 7.3 server with docker-compose 1.25.x & docker 1.13.1

After putting all my file in a directory called `Volume`, I run the docker-compose as indicated by the product editor command :

```
 [root@xxxxxxxxxx etc]# cd /Volume/ ; docker-compose up -d bpcapp
Starting volume_bpcapp_1 ... error

ERROR: for volume_bpcapp_1  Cannot start service bpcapp: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:258: applying cgroup configuration for process caused \"Cannot set property TasksAccounting, or unknown property.\""


ERROR: for bpcapp  Cannot start service bpcapp: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:258: applying cgroup configuration for process caused \"Cannot set property TasksAccounting, or unknown property.\""

ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
[root@xxxxxxxxxx Volume]#
```

Comment: hard to tell.. would you like to share the Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml?

Comment: hello, was docker-compose version issue finally, downgrading it to 1.22 was the solution.  @Efrat there were only a docker-compose.yaml for importing  & was just ok.

Answer (score 0):

was docker-compose version issue finally, downgrading it to 1.22 was the solution.